# python uploading a remote file to GCS , without saving it in the machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

i have a  API which is supposed to give me a zip file , which contains a CSV file within...
my main task is to upload this to GCS

now, the simple approach we could take is

1. Download zip
2. extract CSV and save it locally somewhere
3. Send that locally save CSV to GCS

My question here is , **is there any way using which I can bypass the 2nd step, like I dont want to save the extracted CSV locally...instead I want to pass it directly to the GCS**

Comment: @ZevAverbach thanks a lot man... i have to do a little bit tweaking ..but it helped a lot

Comment: Hey @iron_man83, it seems you have resolved the issue, in that case, it will be helpful for the Community Members if you can post an answer.